# woocommerce payment gateway design

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

I would like to change design of payment gateway, I would like to have payment gateway one beside the other instead to have one below the other.

I tried to do some changes in my woocommerce directory of my theme in the file payment-method.php but without success.

The code of payement gateway:

```
 <li class="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>">
 <input id="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->id ); ?>" <?php checked( $gateway->chosen, true ); ?> data-order_button_text="<?php echo esc_attr( $gateway->order_button_text ); ?>" />
<div class="wallet_box_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>">
<label for="payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>">
<?php echo $gateway->get_title(); ?> <!--<?php echo $gateway->get_icon(); ?>-->
</label>
</div>
<?php if ( $gateway->has_fields() || $gateway->get_description() ) : ?>
<div class="payment_box payment_method_<?php echo $gateway->id; ?>" <?php if ( ! $gateway->chosen ) : ?>style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php $gateway->payment_fields(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

If you have some ideas thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just by css with out altering any code in any template file.

Following is the css selector / rule applied to the li elements.

`.woocommerce-checkout #payment ul.payment_methods li`

Use this selector in your theme css file and add css rules to it.
Following for your reference.

`.woocommerce-checkout #payment ul.payment_methods li{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:30%; //change this percentage according to number of items you have
    padding:5px; //suite the padding amount for yourselves
}`

Your might need to add some more css attributes to this selector so as to match with the UI.

Hope this helps